# Paying rent for accounts when initialising as the developer

Tags: transactions, send-transaction, rent, simulate

I am trying to work out a gasless solution for transactions. Currently partially signing a transaction with the octane core Sdk works for normal transactions but for transactions with instructions that involve the creating of an account, I am faced with a problem where the program needs to have a separate mutable payer account and be set to the `feePayer` when sending the transaction.

The problem is this a big security risk as malicious instructions can drain the `feePayer` account as it is mutable (hence the octane core sdk also has a `validateInstruction` function to make sure that no instruction has `feePayer` as a mutable account)

Possible solutions I thought -

1. Calculate the total gas (including rent) required by the transaction and limit the amount of lamports that can be spent on that transaction. I have no idea how to do this or if it can be done even.
2. Point (1) but if this cannot be done natively, create a new account, transfer the required sol for the transaction (with a little bit extra as buffer) send the transaction using that account. However, I have to then figure out a way to refund the SOL back to the main account if something goes wrong. Also, this assumes that I will be able to calculate the gas including rent accurately

Answer (score 1):

Let's start off by saying: this is a hard problem!  Anytime you make a wallet available to the world, there's a chance of someone draining it, especially if you're using it to fund the rent-exemption for others.

You'll need to create a system for choosing exactly how much your wallet gives away, and to whom.  After that, you can certainly establish a cap of how much your wallet should give away.

If a transaction involves creating an account, you can calculate the required rent-exemption for it off-chain using https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getminimumbalanceforrentexemption and https://docs.solana.com/api/http#getfeeformessage. You can construct the transaction on your side, and include a transfer instruction to that new account -- that way your payer only needs to be mutable in that transfer. When creating accounts, then, rather than use `system_instruction::create_account`, you'll do it "by hand" by having `system_instruction::transfer` + `allocate` + `assign`.

Unfortunately, in most cases you won't be able to recoup those lamports. The only way is through SPL token accounts, by setting your payer as the "close authority".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this for arbitrary programs, but for your own programs, you could transfer the rent/tx fee to the Signer after the logic is complete.

You could figure out what rent will cost on-chain:

`Rent::get()?.minimum_balance(your_struct_size_in_bytes)`

Then transfer this amount from your fee payer to the tx signer. The tx fee is harder, but it rarely moves outside the ballpark of 0.000005 SOL, so you might just pay out a flat rate, which is close enough.